# Grabbing and replacing a DIV with an A to add a link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, each, replacewith

I have written the below and it's almost 100% working for my needs, which is to swap out a given `div` in a series for an `a` link, and grab said `a` link from a button element's href within.  I am using `.each` in order to grab and loop this for each instance.

This particular example is for Wordpress and DIVI, but would work anywhere there is a button that needs to be converted into making the whole div linked.

My issue is that bizarrely, the second time this is running, the value for the `a` only is returning as `undefined`, but the first instance is working just fine.  The rest of the code is also working fine.

Is there something I am doing wrong here, as I cannot see it?

Thanks

```js
jQuery('.all-link').each(function() {

  var treats = jQuery(this).html();
  var linkurl = jQuery(this).find('.et_pb_button_wrapper a').attr('href');
  var allclasses = jQuery(this).attr('class');

  jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery('<a href="' + linkurl + '" class="' + allclasses + '">' + treats + '</a>'));
  jQuery('.hidebtn .et_pb_button_wrapper').closest('.et_pb_button_wrapper').remove();
  jQuery('.handhvr').css('pointer', 'cursor');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4  et_pb_column_2 et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">



  <div id="treatmentlink" class="et_pb_promo et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_center verticalcenter all-link et_pb_cta_0" style="background-color: #dfa926;">
    <div class="et_pb_promo_description">
      <h2 class="et_pb_module_header">YOGA CLASSES</h2>
      <p>Choose from a wide selection of courses to suit most tastes, abilities and ages</p>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper"><a class="et_pb_promo_button et_pb_button" href="/kundalini-yoga-south-devon">click here</a></div>
  </div>

  <div id="treatmentlink" class="et_pb_promo et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_center verticalcenter all-link et_pb_cta_1" style="background-color: #dfa926;">
    <div class="et_pb_promo_description">
      <h2 class="et_pb_module_header">Other CLASS</h2>
      <p>Choose from a wide selection of courses to suit most tastes, abilities and ages</p>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper"><a class="et_pb_promo_button et_pb_button" href="/kundalini-yoga-north-devon">click here</a></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example HTML code so we can  reproduce your problem

Comment: Was just doing that, sorry! Having trouble formatting it without the editor displaying it as html in the viewer - even when wrapping it in `` - bit strange. Essentially that HTML above would be displayed multiple times as a list - it's the second instance onwards that the `href` element returns as undefined. Thanks